# How to solve the error "PLS-00363: expression cannot be used as an assignment target" in Oracle?

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have the following PL/SQL object :

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE TestType AS OBJECT
    (
      firstname VARCHAR2(30),
      lastname VARCHAR2(30),
      MEMBER PROCEDURE dosomething,
      MEMBER function downgrade return number,
      CONSTRUCTOR FUNCTION TestType(fname VARCHAR2, lname VARCHAR2) RETURN SELF AS RESULT
    )
    /

    CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE BODY TestType AS
      CONSTRUCTOR FUNCTION TestType(fname VARCHAR2, lname VARCHAR2)
        RETURN SELF AS RESULT
      IS
      BEGIN
        SELF.firstname := fname;
        SELF.lastname := lname;
        RETURN;
      END;  
      
      MEMBER function downgrade return number IS
      BEGIN
        self.dosomething; /* Compilation Error Here */

        return 1;
      END;
      MEMBER PROCEDURE dosomething IS
      BEGIN
        null;
      END;
    END;
    /
```

It's an example of a complex object I have. Basically from a member function, I need to call a member procedure. When doing so, I'm getting the compilation error:

> PLS-00363: expression cannot be used as an assignment target

Why is this error raised?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although [the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/adobj/object-methods.html#GUID-0A7901B9-EFB4-4243-B01B-2325A3706F6E) says:

> Member methods have a built-in parameter named SELF that denotes the object instance currently invoking the method.
>
> SELF can be explicitly declared, but that is not necessary. ...

it also later says:

> SELF is always the first parameter passed to the method.
>
> - In member functions, if SELF is not declared, its parameter mode defaults to IN.
> - In member procedures, if SELF is not declared, its parameter mode defaults to IN OUT. The default behavior does not include the NOCOPY compiler hint.

You're getting the error because your procedure call

```
self.dosomething;
```

is implicitly passing `self` to the procedure as `IN OUT`, but it's implicitly passed *into* the function as `IN`. That means that it isn't in the right mode for that procedure call - the mode means the procedure could modify `self`, while the function says it won't.

You can avoid the error by changing the mode in the function, by explicitly declaring the `self` argument, in both the type:

```
  MEMBER function downgrade (self in out TestType) return number,
```

and type body:

```
  MEMBER function downgrade (self in out TestType) return number IS
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/248pldqY)

If your real procedure won't modify `self` (maybe unlikely) then you could declare it's `self IN` instead.

It is often said that functions should only return values and shouldn't have side-effects, so arguably that would be more correct - someone calling your member function might not expect it to change anything.

So if `dosomething` *is* changing data then perhaps `downgrade` should also be a procedure, with an `OUT` argument instead of a return value. You then wouldn't need to declare `self` as both would be `IN OUT` by default.

Answer (score 1):

This one compiles successfully:

```
  MEMBER FUNCTION DOWNGRADE RETURN NUMBER IS
    me TestType := SELF;
  BEGIN
    me.dosomething;
    RETURN 1;
  END;
```

But you should test it carefully, whether it is working as expected.

Otherwise you could change the procedure into a function and ignore the return value:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE TestType AS OBJECT
(
  firstname VARCHAR2(30),
  lastname VARCHAR2(30),
  MEMBER FUNCTION dosomething RETURN NUMBER,
  MEMBER FUNCTION DOWNGRADE RETURN NUMBER,
  CONSTRUCTOR FUNCTION TestType(fname VARCHAR2, lname VARCHAR2) RETURN SELF AS RESULT
)
/

CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE BODY TestType AS
  CONSTRUCTOR FUNCTION TestType(fname VARCHAR2, lname VARCHAR2)
    RETURN SELF AS RESULT
  IS
  BEGIN
    SELF.firstname := fname;
    SELF.lastname := lname;
    RETURN;
  END;  
  
  MEMBER FUNCTION DOWNGRADE RETURN NUMBER IS
    ret NUMBER;
  BEGIN
     ret := self.dosomething;
    RETURN 1;
  END;
  MEMBER FUNCTION dosomething RETURN NUMBER IS
  BEGIN
    NULL;
    RETURN NULL;
  END;
END;
/
```

Another approach could be to create a `STATIC PROCEDURE` procedure instead of a `MEMBER PROCEDURE`